java/kotlin library for creating pdf document with different User Details
I have an application where users can do a test and when they succeed I want them to have a certificate with their name and date of accomplishment.
What is the best way to do this and what libraries should I use? My backend is in kotlin.
I want to be able to use any already created certificate template and just include the users data on it. Maybe use a placeholder in the template and insert the real name on runtime? Or are there better ways to handle this? I guess I could also create the whole document programmatically but I really dont know the best way to approach this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The simples solution I see is to create an empty certificate with any graphic design app and export it as PDF. Using Acrobat or other PDF editor add text box form fields in the locations where you need the user data. Then using any Java PDF library you can fill those form fields with actual user information.
Using the PDF4Java library you can fill the form fields like this:
PDFFixedDocument document = new PDFFixedDocument("certificate.pdf");
PDFForm form = document.getForm();

form.getField("firstname").setValue("John");
form.getField("lastname").setValue("Doe");

// Make the form non-editable
form.flattenFields();

document.save("certificate.johndoe.pdf");

Note: I work for the company that develops PDF4Java library.
